# Expected value of length of longest cycle in permutation

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations, expectation, cycles

Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $S_n$ be the collection of permutations $\pi:\{1,\ldots,n\}\to \{1,\ldots,n\}$. For $\pi\in S_n$ let $\text{maxcyc}(\pi)$ denote the length of the longest cycle of $\pi$

The expression $$E_n=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\pi\in S_n}\text{maxcyc}(\pi)$$ gives the expected value of the maximal cycle length of a permutation $\pi\in S_n$.

What is the value of $\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\frac{E_n}{n}$?

Comment: See L. A. Shepp and S. P. Lloyd, Ordered Cycle Lengths in a Random Permutation, Transactions of the American Mathematical Society, Vol. 121, No. 2 (Feb., 1966), pp. 340-357, https://www.jstor.org/stable/1994483?seq=1 – they cite a result of Golomb, according to which your quotient approaches a limit, and then go beyond that.

Comment: The answer is the [Golomb-Dickson constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb%E2%80%93Dickman_constant),  approximately $0.6243299885$.

Comment: John Baez has a series of nice posts about cycles lenghts of random permutations here: https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/permutations/

Comment: The paper "Cycle Lengths in a Permutation are Typically Poisson", by Andrew Granville, is also related

Comment: Thanks everybody for your comments! - @LeechLattice, I think your comment deserves an answer as it is worth spreading the gospel about that constant, so to speak.