# Expected value of maximal cycle length in fixed-point free bijections

Tags: permutations, recreational-mathematics, expectation

$\newcommand{\n}{\{1,\ldots,n\}}$
$\newcommand{\FF}{\text{FF}}$
$\newcommand{\lc}{\text{lc}}$

**Motivation.** A group of my son's peers decided to have a few days of [Secret Santa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_Santa) before last year's Christmas. Everyone receives at least one present from exactly one other kid in the group and everyone else gives to exactly one other kid. One kid, Tom, wondered, whether one can start at the kid $K$ that Tom gives to, go to the person $K'$ that $K$ gives to and so on, and eventually reach everyone until we are back at Tom. I pointed out to him that this is not necessarily true - but we wondered, what the expected size of the largest cycle in a Secret Santa setting might be.

**Formalization.** Let $n$ be a positive integer. By $\FF_n$ we denote the collection of fixed-point-free permutations $\pi:\n\to\n$. For any $\pi \in \FF_n$ we let $\lc(\pi)$ be the lengh of the longest cycle of $\pi$. So $$E_n = \frac{1}{|\FF_n|}\sum_{\pi\in\FF_n}\lc(\pi)$$ is the expected value of the longest cycle in any given fixed-point-free bijection $\pi:\n\to\n$.

What is $\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}E_n/n$?

Comment: The answer for random permutations instead of random derangements is the so-called "Golomb–Dickman constant," as was explained to you previously here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393748. Forcing the permutation to be a derangement should not change much about its expected maximum cycle length (after all, we expect only 1 fixed point for a random permutation). There is a straightfoward generating function approach to this kind of problem; see: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3450759/79593. We just have to change the sums to start at 2 instead of 1 to enforce no fixed points.

Comment: In fact your question is essentially the same as: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1364438. From the graphs displayed in the answer there, you can see how the answer is no different for derangements compared to all permutations.